# How to share state between angular directives using service recipe

Tags: javascript, angularjs, service, share, directive

I'd like to create reusable components for handling birth date selection. The component's structure would look like this:

```
<div ng-controller="userDataController">
  <birth-date birth-day="dateObject">
    <birth-year max-year="2016" range="100" year-label="Year"></birth-year>
      <birth-month month-label="Month"></birth-month>
      <birth-day day-label="Day"></birth-day>
  </birth-date>
</div>
```

I used factory recipe for sharing state between directives and the controller. It works for one set of components, but it cannot handle the case when there are more sets of components e.g. you have to get more birth data in a form. I'm thinking about using angular service recipe (so I could instantiate one service for a component set and so on), but I don't know what would be the best pattern, how to inject the instantiated service to the components. Should I share the service instance via two way data binding? I doesn't seem a good idea considering performance. It would be nice if the directive sets had their own service and could share their data with the help of service and these services were different instances.

Comment: Really not clear what specific problem is. Does `birthDate` directive have isolated scope? If not would need that to be able to pass in different `dateObject`'s

Comment: The problem is that if I want to work with more sets of components, I need more instances of services that help sharing data between parts of the set.

Comment: Would help to see what data structure is like. Should be able to share array